# assigning variable as rootViewController in didMoveToView method doesn't work

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit

When I create a variable in SpriteKit's default "GameScene" class:

```
var viewController = self.view?.window?.rootViewController as GameViewController
```

it works in the touchesBegan method and a few others, however, it always causes an error when declared in "didMoveToView". In a game I'm creating I need it to be called in this method.

The error that comes up is the

"EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0"

error. There is no further information or crashlog.

Thanks to anyone who can aid me in this time of great woe.

Answer (score 0):

`self.view?.window` is `nil` when the `didMoveToView` is called. It's added to the `window hierarchy` only after everything is initialized. What you can do is create a gameViewController property inside the `GameScene` and assign it inside `GameViewController` before `presentScene` is called.

```
class GameScene: SKScene,SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    weak var gameViewController : GameViewController? = nil
}
```

Inside `GameViewController`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Other code

    scene.gameViewController = self
    skView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

You can access it like this

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    println(self.gameViewController?.yourPropertyName)
}
```